# jQuery KeyFilter Plugin Problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, mask, keyfilter

Using keyfilter plugin for jQuery, and all seems to be fine apart from one problem.

I am using a regular expression to filter the element.

```
$('#nameVal').keyfilter(/[0-9a-zA-Z]/);
```

The odd thing is, this is not only allowing alpha-numeric characters but it is also allowing '(' to be entered. In fact, it doesn't matter what expression I pass to the keyfilter, I can't stop '(' being allowed in the textbox.

Has anyone else experienced this problem and is there a solution?

Comment: I just tried it in a jQuery keyfilter demo and it worked perfectly, maybe you have a mistake somewhere in your code, or it's a bug in old keyfilter versions!

Comment: http://jquery-keyfilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demo.html
This demo page has exactly the same problem for me. The line in the source that adds the filter is $('#by-re').keyfilter(/[ABC]/i); but I can still enter the open bracket character. Looks like a bug in KeyFilter.

Comment: If I pass a function such as $('#nameVal').keyfilter(function(c){return false;}); I can still enter (. It seems that when I enter the open bracket character it is bypassing the keyfilter. This is happening in IE and Chrome for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

The isSpecialKey function in the KeyFilter plugin returns true if the keycode is 40, which is the keycode for '('. This means that the test is never performed on the character.

```
var isSpecialKey = function(e)
{
    var k = e.keyCode;
    var c = e.charCode;
    return k == 9 || k == 13 || /*(k == 40 && (!$.browser.opera || !e.shiftKey)) ||*/ k == 27 ||
        k == 16 || k == 17 ||
        (k >= 18 && k <= 20) ||
        ($.browser.opera && !e.shiftKey && (k == 8 || (k >= 33 && k <= 35) || (k >= 36 && k <= 39) || (k >= 44 && k <= 45)))
        ;

    };
```

Commenting out the bit of code as I have above fixes the problem. Not entirely sure what effect this will have in other browsers, but it works in IE8 and Chrome.